# I want to open Windows Settings screen via VBA code

Tags: vba, windows, shell, command, settings

1. Press **Windows**+**R** in order to open **Run** Dialog Box.
2. Type **ms-settings:** into **Run** Dialog Box.
3. Press **OK** in order to open **Windows Settings** Screen.

Do you know any ***VBA*** code which gives me same result like above actions?

I mean I just want to open **Windows Settings** screen via ***VBA*** code.

Please note that I am a **Windows 10** user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use API `ShellExecute` to execute script `Start-Process ms-settings:`

```vb
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
        ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lpOperation As String, _
        ByVal lpFile As String, _
        ByVal lpParameters As String, _
        ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
        ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
    Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
        ByVal hwnd As Long, _
        ByVal lpOperation As String, _
        ByVal lpFile As String, _
        ByVal lpParameters As String, _
        ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
        ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
#End If

Sub OpenSystemSettings()
    ShellExecute 0, "open", "ms-settings:", vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

---

***Update:***

> Question: how to close Windows Settings screen via ShellExecute? Like pressing Alt+F4

```vb
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
        ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _
        ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal wMsg As Long, _
        ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
        lParam As Any) As LongPtr
#Else
    Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
        ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _
        ByVal hwnd As Long, _
        ByVal wMsg As Long, _
        ByVal wParam As Long, _
        lParam As Any) As Long
#End If
Sub CloseSystemSettings()
    Dim hwnd As LongPtr
    Dim result As LongPtr
    Const WIN_TITLE = "Settings"  ' modify as needed for non-English release
    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, WIN_TITLE)
    If hwnd = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Can't find window: " & WIN_TITLE
    Else
        result = SendMessage(hwnd, &H10, 0, ByVal 0&)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: **Additional Question:** Do you know how to close **Windows Settings** screen via **ShellExecute**? Like pressing ``Alt+F4``.

Comment: I've posted a code snippet to close  Windows Settings.